# Java Object Reference and Java Methods

Tags: java, methods, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, object-reference

I am unable to understand how this works

```
public void addToRule(Rule r) {
    if (!getRuleList().contains(r)) {
        getRuleList().addElement(r);
    }
}
```

If I run this code:

```
obj.addToRule(r);
System.out.println(getRuleList().contains(r));
```

it prints out `true` how can this happen?

btw ruleList is a vector member of the main class and is not a static variable(don't think this matters but sharing anyway).

```
import java.util.Vector;


public class RuleEngine{

    private Vector ruleList = new Vector();

    public Vector getRuleList(){
        return ruleList;
    }

    public void addToRule(Rule r){
        if(!getRuleList().contains(r))
            getRuleList().addElement(r);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        RuleEngine re = new RuleEngine();
        Rule r = new Rule("Rule1");
        re.addToRule(r);
        System.out.println(re.getRuleList().contains(r));
    }
}

class Rule{
    public String name = "";
    public Rule(String nam){
        this.name=nam;
    }
}
```

OK people have told me that this works because of the pass by reference in java. I get it. but what can i do to get a copy of that object instead of its reference?

Comment: It should return true. What is the problem anyway?! Reformat your code and make it more understable, otherwise others will give you -1 ;-)

Comment: i am unable to understand this behavior

Comment: it doesn't compile because that's not the full code

Comment: @Piyush: shouldn't it be `System.out.println(obj.getRuleList().contains(r));`? or is getRuleList static? or is the test code being called inside obj (obj = this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you have not completely understood what the difference is between a value and a reference in Java. Basically, objects are always passed around as references in Java.

Consider

```
class Test {
    private List list = new ArrayList();
    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

The `getList()` method will return a **reference** to the `list` object. It will **not** return a copy of the `list` object. Doing something like

```
Test test = new Test();
String s = "ABC";
test.getList().add(s);
System.out.println(test.getList().contains(s));
```

Will return true since the first time `getList()` is called, a **referece** to the list is returned, on which `add(s)` is invoked. The second time `getList()` is called, it returns a **reference** to the same list, not a copy of it, not a new list - the same reference. Calling `contains(s)` will return true since it the same list onto which the object `s` was added.

Consider this, however.

```
Test test1 = new Test();
Test test2 = new Test();
String s = "ABC";
test1.add(s);
System.out.println(test2.getList().contains(s));
```

This will print out "false". Why? `test1.getList()` returns a reference to the list inside **test1** and `test2.getList()` returns a reference to the list inside **test2**. Here, `s` was added to test1:s list, so it will not be contained inside test2:s list.

Comment: what happens when i implement the method `addToRule()` like this: 
 `public void addToRule(Rule r){
  if(!getRuleList().contains(r)){
   Vector list = getRuleList();
   list.addElement(r);
  }
 }
`

Comment: i tried doing it and found that it still gives out true. what can i do to get a copy of rulelist and not a reference?

Comment: That depends. Do you want just a copy of the list containing the same object references as the original list? If so, you can use the addAll method (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29). If you want it to contain copies of all objects in the list, you will have to manually clone all the objects and add them to a new list. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29.

Comment: ohhh... so there's no easy way huh?

Comment: I suppose that depends on your definition of "easy". Just getting a new list with the same objects, using addAll(...) is not very complicated, per se. Cloning objects is inherently a bit more complex. Java has very limited ability in terms of default abilities in copying objects. It relies on you, the implementor, to define the clone() behavior of your classes that needs to support being cloned. I would also advice you to take a step back and examine what it is that requires you to copy/clone this list. The number of use-cases where this is really required is, in my experience, very limited.

Comment: sry I am not stuck with some problem over here. I just wanted to know what can be done in such cases. for example if it were a string or a number and then i manipulate it... Oh holy molly, I just answered my own question by this use  case, if it is a string or integer then it is the copy that you get right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `getRuleList()` is returning a *reference* to a List (or something similar).  Think of it as a pointer (or more specifically, a copy of a pointer) if you're familiar with C.  You're working on the same underlying instance of the object when you call `getRuleList()`.

For proof, try: `System.out.println(getRuleList() == getRuleList())`;  The `==` operator will only compare if the two references are pointing to the same object (not a deep equal like `.equals`).  You'll see that until you call `setRuleList()` with a different object *reference* that the statement holds true.

These assumptions are of course without seeing your full code.

Answer (score 1):

So, to answer your questions you have to at first know how Java passes Variables.

a Variable has a value:

```
int i = 1234;
Person p = new Person("Peter");
```

Now, the Variable i contains exactly 1234, while the Variable p contains the Memory Adress of the created Person.

so i contains 1234 and p contains the adress (let's say a4dfi3).

```
anyMethodYouLike(p);
System.out.println(p.getName());
public void anyMethodYouLike(Person somePerson) {
   somePerson.rename("Homer");
}
```

so in this example, we give the Method anyMethodYouLike the Variable p... wait! we give the Method the value of the Variable (a4dfi3). The Method then calls rename on this Variable (which still has the same adress as p has, hence it modifies the same Person that p points to).
So, after the Method, the Name of the Person p points to, gets printed, which results in "Homer".

```
someOtherMethod(p);
System.out.println(p.getName());
public void someOtherMethod(Person somePerson) {
   somePerson = new Person("Walter");
}
```

In THIS example we still give the adress of our Person called "Peter" to the Method. But this time, the Method creates a new Person in somePerson (therefore overriding the adress in somePerson to.. let's say 13n37s.
BUT! the Person at a4dfi3 wasn't changed! The print call still outputs "Peter" and not "Walter".

Now, let's see how this behaves with primitives:

```
someMethod(i);
System.out.println(i);
public void someMethod(int someInt) {
   someInt++;
}
```

So, the Value of i (1234) gets passed to someInteger. Then someInteger gets incremented to 1235. But i is still 1234.

This is the big difference between Objects and primitives in Java.

Hope I could help,
Ferdi265

Answer (score 0):

It should always print `true`, because you add the rule to the rule list in case it is not there. What happens is:

- you tell the object to add add a rule to its rule list
- the objects checks if the rule exists, and if it doesn't, adds it

So it is guaranteed to contain the rule after the code is executed.

Comment: yes but i am not calling the copy of rulelist to which i added the rule. what i think is that the appropriate code for this should have been: `if (!getRuleList().contains(r)) {
        setRuleList(getRuleList().addElement(r));
    }`

Comment: look i dont want it to give out false. this is some preexisting code that i am looking at and am unable to understand when we can do this and when we can't.

Comment: Whatever it is, if you don't show the whole class, we can't help

Comment: my answer remains valid - I don't see a reason for it to print `false`.

Comment: yeah but you don't quite understand what i was asking. the end result is unimportant. i did not get how the reference was passed. please look at the tags before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: there is no pass-by-reference/value issues here. You don't reassign anything inside the method. I really don't understand which part exactly you don't get